# Density of random variables

Tags: probability, density-function

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with respective densities:
$f_X (x) = xe^{-\frac{x^2}{ 2}} 1_{]0,+\infty[} (x)$ and $ f_Y (y) =  \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{1-y^2}} 1_{]-1,1[} (y)$

Let $U:=XY$ and $V:=X\sqrt{1-Y^2}$

I try to check whether U and V are independent and which law they follow.

What I did:

After some calculations, I found the density of $(U,V)$:

$ f_{(U,V)}(u,v)=\frac{1}{\pi } e^{-\frac{u^2}{ 2}}1_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{v^2}{ 2}}1_{\mathbb{R}_+^* }$
Which mean that $(U,V)$ follows a $ \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ law (because $u^2+v^2=x^2$) and that  U and V are independent because $f_{(U,V)}$ can be factored as the products of densities of $U$ and $V$

My question:

There is a factor $\frac{1}{\pi}$ and I don't know to which density it will belong: to $U$ density or to $V$ density?

Many thanks!

Comment: You haven't mentioned independence of $X$ and $Y$, based on which everything rests. 

You have found that $\displaystyle f_{U,V}(u,v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^2/2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-v^2/2}\mathbf1_{u\in\mathbb{R}\,,\,v>0}=f_U(u)f_V(v)$.

So $U$ has the standard normal density, whereas $V$ has the [half-normal density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution), independently of $U$.

Comment: I am sorry, indeed variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent

Answer (score 1):

Just remember that

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\rm d}u ~e^{-u^2/2} = 1 ~~~\mbox{and}~~~
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}{\rm d}v ~e^{-v^2/2} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

If you multiply this two you get the normalization of $f(u,v)$

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\rm d}u \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}{\rm d}v ~e^{-u^2/2} ~e^{-v^2/2} = \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}}{\rm d}u \int_{\mathbb{R}^+}{\rm d}v ~e^{-u^2/2} ~e^{-v^2/2} = 1
$$

So the factor $1/\pi$ actually is shared by the two distributions